# Android: AsynTask crashing application when showing an alertdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have an AsynTask that crashes the whole application when doInBackground method calls another class that tries to show an alertdialog.

The following is my AsynTask,

```
private class ReserveAppointmentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(RESERVING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        WebServiceResponse.appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity.this, appointmentObj);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void response) {
        removeDialog(RESERVING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }

}
```

The WebserviceResponse.appointmentReservation method contains the following code and I know for a fact that it enters the if condition stated below,

```
public static void appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity activity, Appointment appointmentObj){
    SetAppointmentResponse setAppointmentResponse = SetAppointmentResponse.extractJSONResponse(response);

    if(setAppointmentResponse.checkResponse()== RESPONSES.SUCCESSFULL){
        Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog(activity);                            
    }

}
```

The Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog contains the following,

```
public static void initAppointmentReservedDialog(final Activity activity){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.appointment_reserved_dialog)).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok_button_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(activity, MainOptionsActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(nextScreen);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I get the following fatal exception in my log,

```
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:913)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.util.Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog(Dialogs.java:277)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.webservice.WebServiceResponse.appointmentReservation(WebServiceResponse.java:288)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.gui.AppointmentConfirmationActivity$ReserveAppointmentTask.doInBackground(AppointmentConfirmationActivity.java:182)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.gui.AppointmentConfirmationActivity$ReserveAppointmentTask.doInBackground(AppointmentConfirmationActivity.java:1)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-18 10:59:34.882: E/AndroidRuntime(4885):     ... 4 more
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't change the UI component from background thread.

Comment: Is `Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog` work with `Activity` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason as @PareshMayani said: You can't update UI while doing inside `doInBackground()`. Yes you can but for that you have to include either `runOnUiThread()` or use `onPostExecute()`

I would suggest such changes to update UI after the process

```
private class ReserveAppointmentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(RESERVING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {        
        return WebServiceResponse.appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity.this, appointmentObj);            
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer response) {
        removeDialog(RESERVING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        if(response == RESPONSES.SUCCESSFULL){

            Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog(activity);                            
        }
    }
}
```

now change your method `appointmentReservation()` like this

```
public static int appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity activity, Appointment appointmentObj){
        SetAppointmentResponse setAppointmentResponse = SetAppointmentResponse.extractJSONResponse(response);
        return setAppointmentResponse.checkResponse();
}
```

Comment: Reason of crashing app: You can't update UI while doing inside `doInBackground()`. Yes you can but for that you have to include either `runOnUiThread()` or use `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @PareshMayani I would have written the reason/problem, but actually OP and I with other users had already discussed the reason. So I skipped, but I think it is better to include here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the part that modifies the UI to the `onPostExecute` method..

```
@Override
protected SetAppointmentResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {     
    return WebServiceResponse.appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity.this, appointmentObj);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SetAppointmentResponse response) {
    if(response.checkResponse()== RESPONSES.SUCCESSFULL){

        Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog(activity);                            
    }
    removeDialog(RESERVING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
}
```

And `appointmentReservation` needs to be modified to:

```
public static SetAppointmentResponse appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity activity, Appointment appointmentObj){

    return SetAppointmentResponse.extractJSONResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that would require a major change of my classes design and interaction together, is there any way to keep my Dialog calls in another class?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you cannot change the UI from a background thread..this is why the method onPostExecute exists

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Handler object to do what you want.

In your WebServiceResponse class add this static method (which initializes a new Handler)

```
public static Handler initHandler() {
    return new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                Dialogs.initAppointmentReservedDialog(activity);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Have a call to this method in your ReserveAppointmentTask class in the onPreExecute method.
Keep a reference to this Handler and pass it to the appointmentReservation method.
Then modify the code of this method like this:

```
public static void appointmentReservation(AppointmentConfirmationActivity activity, Appointment appointmentObj, Handler handler){

    SetAppointmentResponse setAppointmentResponse = SetAppointmentResponse.extractJSONResponse(response);

    if(setAppointmentResponse.checkResponse()== RESPONSES.SUCCESSFULL){

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);                            
    }

}
```

To have a better understanding of Handler have a look on this great tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is more suitable to use the code posted in the other answers. Upvoted though :)